# Inserting Images on the Custom UI Editor

Tags: image, excel, user-interface, editor, ribbon

I'm using the custom UI editor to upload images to a custom ribbon tab. I need the images to look like this:

[image: good results]

but currently they are looking like this:

[image: bad results]

These images are directly from Microsoft shapes. I tried saving them the shapes directly but they were really messy. There must be a way to get the shapes perfect as per the first image - I'm just not sure how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Your images need to be saved in exactly 16x16 pixel size.  Anything else, and they will be scaled to fit a 16x16 area, and thus have fuzzy lines.

Your top image (the rectangle) measures 16 pixels wide by 10 pixels tall.  If that is the extent of that image, then when you import it, it will get stretched.  You need to also include the white (or empty) space around the image (in this case, above and below) when you create the image.

[image]

The example above shows the exact same 16x10 px rectangle, in two different formats.  The top image included the white space above and below the rectangle and was saved as a 16x16 px image.  The bottom image only had the 16x10 px rectangle and was saved as a 16x10 px image, so it was stretched by the UI editor to fit the 16x16 available space.

Comment: For the PowerPoint customui, large icons seems to be 32x32 pixels, while normal icons seems to be 15x15 px. Am I wrong about the small icons, because they actually should be 16x16 px and maintain the same aspect ratio, and also correspond to what you have stated about icons in the customui editor?